# How to avoid wrapping unless necessary using CSS max-width?

Tags: css

Naively, I thought that `max-width: max-content;` would be as wide as needed to avoid wrapping, but that seems not to be the case, per this example.  **Is there any way in CSS to set a container element to be only as wide as needed to avoid text wrapping up to 100% width**, but still allow text wrapping once at 100% width?  In other words, make it 100% width unless the max-content **without wrapping** is narrower, in which case make it max-content.  I think running this snippet will illustrate what I want -- the text wraps even when there is enough horizontal room to make the container wider.

In other words, it seems like `max-content` really isn't the maximum width of the content without word-wrapping--it is some lesser width with word-wrapping, though I don't understand what. This example wraps even I though I think it shouldn't have to.

```css
.container {
    border: solid;
    max-width: max-content;
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    width: 75%;
}

.right { 
   border-left:  solid;
   width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Text that I don't want to wrap unless needed when the outer container is at width 100%</div>
  <div class="right">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is related to the percentage (a bit complex). Remove them to see what is happening

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit, perhaps?  I still find myself a little unsure of the end goal.  Are you just looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9oj6L0eb/39/)?

Comment: @Jake Yes, except I want the width of the outer container to shrink to the content when the content is short.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, it does seem to work as I wish when I remove the percentages.  How can I get it to work with the percentages?

Comment: short answer: you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

The OP pointed out that my original solution did not work for mid-length strings.  I don't understand the technical reason for why not, so if someone wants to explain it, that would be awesome, buuut I did find another way to do what the OP is looking for, hopefully correctly this time:

```css
.container{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>
     Some short content
   </div>
   <div>
     lorem ipsum
   </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
   <div>
     Some medium content should not wrap this text unless needed hello goodbye where am i  
   </div>
   <div>
     lorem ipsum
   </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
   <div>
     Some really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second line
   </div>
   <div>
     lorem ipsum
   </div>
</div>
```

### END EDIT

If I understand the question correctly, you can accomplish this with `display: inline-flex`, as below:

```css
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left{
  width: 75%;
}

.right{
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Some short content</div>
  <div class="right">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Some really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second lineSome really really long content that should wrap this text onto a second line</div>
  <div class="right">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="left">Some medium content should not wrap this text unless needed</div> 
<div class="right">lorem ipsum</div>
```

[Quick overview of inline vs block](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: And if I'm not understanding the question, please let me know which part of this solution isn't up to snuff...

Comment: I think my problem isn't with really long or really short content, but when the content nears a full line but shouldn't wrap. I've edited your snippet with a third example and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, and a good catch.  I honestly don't know why that doesn't work, and after playing around with it for a while, I still can't figure it out.  However, I found another way to do what you're looking for, using `inline-grid` instead of `inline-flex`, and I'll edit my answer to include it as a second snippet.

Comment: I guess that my new solution doesn't wrap the "lorem ipsum" on the first, short example, unlike the original solution.  Maybe this is also a deal breaker, I am not sure.